# A Folder in Windows has lost all permissions, how can I fix or delete it?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

In Windows 10, I have a folder that has lost every permission and even the ownership.

If I choose right-click > Security, all lists of permissions are empty and it says the owner could not be evaluated. If I try to add a permission, e.g. of System, or try to change the owner, the settings are not stored.

I would like either to fix the folder or to delete and recreate it. But the system doesn't allow to delete, even if I start a shell or a file explorer as administrator.

What is the correct way in Windows to clean up such orphans?

Thanks a lot for any hint.

---

**Edit** Please see the picture below that illustrates how important option controls are missing. Also, chkdsk seems not possible immediately (but it can be scheduled).

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would first suggest running `chkdsk /f` on the disk, which will make sure the security information isn't corrupted. It should restore the directory to some 'standard' permissions.

If you're an administrator, you should be always able to take ownership using `takeown`, and then write new ACL using e.g. `icacls … /reset`.

Comment: `takeown /F` was our rescue here :-)

Comment: I am getting `ERROR: Access is denied.` with `takeown /F <foldername>`.

Comment: Restarting Windows removed the file. Seems it was a ghost file or sth...

Answer (score 4):

Restart your computer. This may be a folder that has failed to delete, it should disapear on a restart and can be re-created safely

Comment: I don't know why this got a downvote - I had this issue, and this was exactly the solution in my case. Same for user2173353 according to the comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: I have this strange problem that when I try to delete a resource (let's say an exe file) that is being used by another process, the file loses ownership. Every single time. Example: A .NET console project. After I build, then clean the directory, my exe loses ownership. As a result, I have to update the output directory. Obviously I can't restart my computer every time this happens. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

On the parent folder, right click, choose properties, security.

From there go to <kbd>Advanced</kbd>

If you are using a standard user, press the button Change permissions and supply administrative credentials.

You should now see a checkmark at the bottom stating:

`[ ]` Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object.

Check this checkbox and press Apply.

Every subfolder will now get their permissions reset, including the one you lost access to.

If you can't afford any other folder to be affected, you can try to move the folder in question to a new folder and try it as such, or move all other folders away.

Comment: Important controls are missing, please see the picture I've added. That's why I'm stuck with the context menu way. However your suggestion is the right start. Would it make sense to dig deeper with powershell?

Comment: You need to go higher in the directory tree until you find a folder you have access to. Do note that the inetpub folder is part of IIS and altering permissions may cause IIS to stop working correctly.

Comment: If you're an administrator, you should be always able to take ownership using `takeown`, and then write new ACL using e.g. `icacls … /reset`.

Comment: @LPChip thanks for the extra explanation. You are right in mentioning IIS. Some of the folders there have additional write permissions for the `IIS_IUSRS`. By reinitializing the permissions from the parent, I have to correct those permissions. Would be easy if I had direct access to the machine. So this way became the fallback solution. Luckily, `takeown` worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue where ICACLS and the TAKEOWN commands were not getting it done. I was using ICACLS and after finding this post I also tried TAKEOWN:

```
icacls N:\* /grant UserName:(oi)(ci)f
takeown /F N:\*
```

What finally corrected the issue was explicitly setting the INHERITANCE switch in ICACLS:

```
icacls N:\* /grant UserName:(oi)(ci)f /inheritance:e
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command prompt or powershell with admin privileges, try either of the following:

```
robocopy [source directory] [dest directory] /COPYALL /SECFIX /SEC
```

or if that fails, try:

```
robocopy [source directory] [dest directory] /COPY:S
```

In recent versions of robocopy, the `/TIMFIX` or `/SECFIX` switches are no longer supported. If you have scripts that use these switches you must edit them to use `/COPY:` instead.  `/COPY:T` replaces the old `/TIMFIX`, and `/COPY:S` replaces the old `/SECFIX`.