# C drive have So many temp file and it is not deletable

Tags: windows-10, permissions

i have windows 10 anniversary update and i have problem with c drive i have many temp file in c drive like marked in image below

[image: Orange Marked is .temp file, Yellow marked is folder that i created new folder, and cyan marked is .csv file]

and also some .csv file (that are created daily one .csv file and yes i can delete it but i want to stop creating it) and .temp file i can not  delete it give below error

[image: Error during deletion process]

i have try to change owner but error occur i have no rights to change owner or unable to change owner

and for new folder that are marked as yellow color this folder that i created my self but i have create only two new folder using right click and new and folder and it created 11 new folder and i have no rights to give name of folder during creation and i have also no rights for deleting those folder same error as temp file and this error occur when i was installing new software on c drive like python2.7 it create folder but during installation of python it error like that do not have permission to change content or need permission to write on python27 folder and also python27 folder unable to delete please give me an solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Folder in Windows has lost all permissions, how can I fix or delete it?](http://superuser.com/questions/1162798/a-folder-in-windows-has-lost-all-permissions-how-can-i-fix-or-delete-it)

Comment: It was not working i have tried before twice and now once but still not solved

Comment: Use the built-in Administrator account to delete the files.

Comment: i have an one account and that is administrator and how to use built-in administrator account